# WIX: Change install directory from c# class parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, wix, wix3.7

I'm creating an install wizard and i have a page where you can choose where you want to install the program. In my c# class i have InstallPath that keeps the exact directory i want to install the program.

By default it's c:\Program Files.

In my WiX setup file i have that:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id ="Folder" Name="SomeFolder"/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

My problem is that i don't know how to tell this Wix setup to install in InstallPath.
For example if InstallPath is changed to D:\SomeFolder\Here
I want to install there not in Program Files again.

Comment: If you are using an application to drive the installer then-at that point-it has nothing to do with WiX. WiX Setups build Windows Installer packages. You'll need to consult the documentation for the Windows Installer API (e.g. `msiexec.exe`) that you are using to pass the property value for SOMEFOLDER (must be all uppercase so it is publicly accessible). You might also want to consider a WiX Bootstrapper project to driver the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these custom action to change the property value during install:

1. a custom action which changes the directory property value scheduled before CostFinalize
2. a type 35 custom action which changes the directory path (should be scheduled after CostFinalize)

For example:

```
<CustomAction Id="ChangeDir" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[SomeValueorPropertyhere]"/>
```

2.Schedule the action during the InstallExecution phase (must be after the CostFinalize step):

```
<Custom Action="ChangeDir" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

to change the path is:

```
<Product Id="*"> 
    <Property Id="ROOTDRIVE">
        <![CDATA[D:\]]>
    </Property>
</Product>
```

and for the new path D:\SomeFolder\Here, will be something like this.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="SomeFolder" Name="SomeFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Here"/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

greetings,