# wix file directory change based on user "per user" or "per machine" choice

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.8

I am using WixUI_Advanced and currently cant figure out how to dynamically change the location of the directory for the needed files based on what the user choses in InstallScopeDlg.

This is what i have; i need to be able to change "ProgramFilesFolder" to "LocalAppDataFolder"

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" >
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728438/1766402

Comment: The directory ID must be all uppercase characters because it must be passed from the UI to the execute sequence to take effect.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html

Answer (score 1):

That standard way to perform single package authoring that just works is described here, together with how the folder changes work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx